# HTTP to FTP with remote client

Tags: ftp, http, rsync, file-transfer

- **short version**: a working equivalent to `scp -3 http://user:pass@example.org/somefile ftp://user:pass@ftpserver/my/path`
- **detailed version**:

  ```
      +------+               +-------+             +-------------+
      | HTTP +---------------> linux +------------->  FTP server |
      +------+    WWW        +-------+    LAN      +-------------+
  ```

  - I have a HTTP ressource on the web. let's say http://example.org/somefile
  - I have a linux host (RaspberryPi) connected to the below FTP server
  - I have a FTP server (mediacenter box)

  **I want to transfer the HTTP file to the FTP server through the linux host.** without storing the whole file on the linux host, just acting as buffer between endpoints

What is the easy way to do this ?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mount the ftp directory:

```
curlftpfs ftp.yourserver.com /mnt/ftp/ -o user=username:password
```

Then you can easily download the selected files to this folder:

```
wget http://user:pass@example.org/somefile -O /mnt/ftp/your/path/somefile
```

At finally umount ftp:

```
fusermount -u /mnt/ftp
```

Comment: If writing a custom program is out of question, I support this answer: it lays the basics quite correctly: 1) use any command-line HTTP client to download the resource; 2) since they assume they download onto a file system, have a way to "export" your remote FTP directory as a local filesystem mount.

Comment: I was hoping for an existing tool that handles both protocols. but that way remains simple so it's ok !

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is probably to build an SSH tunnel. Your machine connects to the linux machine via ssh, and this machine then forwards all traffic on that tunnel to a second host. On your localhost a port is opened, and you could simply connect an FTP client to that port, and it will be forwarded to the FTP server.

```
ssh -L <localport>:<ftpserver>:21 user@<linux FQDN>
```

Comment: I am sorry but I don't understand which hosts of my example you mean by each "machine" :s